# How to turn below code block to Flink style

Tags: apache-flink

We have some code like below:

```html
  for(int i = 0 ; i < 10; i ++ ) {

      //do something ... 
      //doing calculating
      //do something else 


      for(int j = 0; j <  10000 )   {
            //do something calculations..
            //calculating more...
            //Getting result....

      }


 }
```

The times of inner loop is much more than the times of outer loop.

How to turn it to be Flink style?

Comment: If there only has the inner loop, I know we can process the calculation in parallelism based on Flink.

Comment: But now, according to business logic, there needs outer loop, then how to handle this?

Answer (score -1):

We can put env.execute(); in outer loop. Then Flink will handle it. Done!